# I'm getting this error when I add theme data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-theme, flutter-material

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_application_1/pages/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(my_application_1());

}
class my_application_1 extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: home_page()
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown
      ),
    );
    
  }
}
```

ERROR SHOWING IN THEME - `Expected to find ','.dart(expected_token)`

Comment: Add a `,` (comma) after this `home: home_page(),`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a ',' after `home: homePage()`.

Just add it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_application_1/pages/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(my_application_1());

}
class my_application_1 extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: home_page(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown
      ),
    );
    
  }
}
```